# How can I make Xcode ignore xcodeproj in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode9

I have been working on a C project using Xcode9. I don't want to push my .xcodeproj directory into the GitHub. I use the source control menu inside the Xcode to sync with GitHub.

I have added the following line into my .gitignore file:

```
*.xcodeproj/
DerivedData/
*.pbxproj
*xcworkspace
```

but it won't work. When I commit, Xcode would still push my xcodeproj directory into the GitHub. How can I ignore these files in Xcode9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That might be because those files are already tracked (making the `.gitignore` directive  moot)

Try and remove them  from the index

```
git rm --cached -r *.xcodeproj/
git rm --cached -r DerivedData/
git rm --cached -r *.pbxproj
git rm --cached -r *xcworkspace
```

The `--cached` option will make sure you keep those files on the disk (and remove them only form the index).